# Expansion of $\cos \sqrt x $?

Tags: taylor-expansion

If my $x$ belongs to non-negative real numbers then what is the expansion of $\cos \sqrt x$ . Is it sufficient to substitute $\sqrt x$ in place of $x$ in $\cos x$ expansion ? But I see differentiability issues at $x=0$ in case of substitution.

Comment: Try the substitution! Since the series for $\cos \theta$ only uses _even_ powers of $\theta$, all the problematic terms vanish! You know the resulting series converges for $x>0$, and it certainly converges for $x=0$, so its radius of convergence is infinite, and you get an analytic continuation to negative reals (and arbitrary complex numbers) for free!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x\geq 0$.
$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+...$$
therefore
$$\cos(\sqrt x)=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{4!}-\frac{x^3}{6!}+...$$

Comment: Of course, the expansion is*valid* only for $x\ge 0$ (so it's not really an expansion *around* $0$)

Comment: @Hagen: It's a valid expansion of the unique analytic continuation of $\cos\sqrt x$, though.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Of course !